I'm trying to deploy a react + vite project and keep getting the same MIME error message and a blank page
Not sure if this is really that difficult of an issue, but I've been stuck on it for awhile now. Trying to deploy a website to hostinger by uploading my git repository. It runs fine locally, but once it's deployed all I get is a blank page and this error message in the devtools:
"Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
Here's my repository: https://github.com/spudsbeets/cocktail-clash-vite.git
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!
Tried adding .htaccess file, .gitaccess file, tried npm run build (dist)
